# Consumo de webservice con autenticacion desde formulario ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Me surgio un problema al intentar consumir un web service xml desde JS con ajax ya que este tiene autenticacion previa a la entrega de informacion y no puedo inspeccionar el formulario de las credenciales que solicita.

intente lo siguiente:

```
function webservice() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "urlwebserv",
        type: "Post",
        data: { username: "username", password: "password" },
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("Data").each(function () {
                $(this).find("id").text();
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Do!");
        }

    });
}
```

tbn intente esto:

```
function webservice() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "urlwebserv",
        type: "Post",
        username: "username", 
        password: "password",
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("Data").each(function () {
                $(this).find("id").text();
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Do!");
        }

    });
}
```

La pregunta es ¿se puede mediante ajax ingresar a un web service que pide autenticacion por formulario? y luego acceder a la información que entregan desde un xml

errores en browser:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
>   (Unauthorized).
>
> Failed to load urlwebsrv: Response to preflight request doesn't pass
>   access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:53854' is
>   therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

favor ayuda.

Comment: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"
Ahi está tu respuesta, busca la causa de ese error y como, o quitar la validación de "cross origin request" en el servidor, o bien agregar el header en primer lugar en el request que carga esa primera página

Comment: Amigo es configuración del servidor, no tuya, ka explicación es la siguiente y como dice tu error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`  La configuración del servidor no acepta conexiones de otro dominio.

Comment: gracias. pero como lo haria usted para solucionarlo ya que me ecuentro en el trabajo y nose si es una buena respuesta para esto he probado de mil formas y con web services sin autenticacion y aun asi el mismo error.

Comment: @MaxFuentes ¿Tienes acceso al servidor donde está tu servicio que consumes?

Comment: no tengo acceso de hecho esta en otro pais estoy en chile y el webservice es de ecuador

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por razones de seguridad, los exploradores restringen las solicitudes HTTP de origen cruzado iniciadas dentro de un script.

Por ejemplo, `XMLHttpRequest` sigue la política de mismo-origen . Por lo que, una aplicación usando `XMLHttpRequest` solo puede hacer solicitudes HTTP a su propio dominio.

Sin embargo, para efectos de pruebas, instala esta extensión [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) en **Chrome**. La activas, y podrás permitir conexiones entre dominios.

[image: imagen]

Comment: Me funciono Colega muchas gracias. 




function prueba3()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "webserv", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}